# Difficult Limiting Function of a Simple Sequence of Functions

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, convergence-divergence

Suppose that for $n \ge 1$, $n \in \mathbb N$, we have a function $f_n(x)$ piecewise defined on the domain $x \in [0,1]$ in the following way:

$$f_n(x)=\cases{1 & \text{for } x=1/n \cr 0 & \text{otherwise}}$$

The limiting function of the sequence $\{f_n(x)\}$ is $f(x)$, which we can define as follows:

$$ f(x)\equiv\lim_{n\to \infty}f_n(x)$$

What is $f(x)$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$\forall x\in (0,1],\exists N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $\forall n >N,\frac{1}{n}<x\Rightarrow \forall n >N,f_n(x)=0\Rightarrow f(x)=0$, so $\forall x\in (0,1],f(x)=0$.
Also $\forall n \in\mathbb{N},f_n(0)=0$, so $f(0)=0$.

Finally $\forall x\in [0,1],f(x)=0$.

Comment: For any $n$ we have $\text{max}[f_n(x)]=1$. So why does $\lim_{n\to \infty}[\text{max}[f_n(x)]=0$ ?

Comment: @user5556984 $f_n$ is not continuous so there are no reason that $\text{max}[f_n(x)]=1 \Rightarrow \lim_{n\to \infty}[\text{max}[f_n(x)]=1$.

Comment: Huh. It is a bit counter-intuitive that the discontinuous point disappears but I think your answer is correct. The limiting function need not preserve all the properties of the functions which approach it (like in this case the existence of a discontinuous point).

Comment: Well you also have that the pointwise limit of continuous functions is not necessarely continuous. You need the uniform convergence of the sequence of functions to have this result.